# Date.parse in ios?

Tags: ios, date

Is there any method in ios which is similar to date.parse() in javascript?

```
    value = Date.parse(date.value + ' ' + time.value);// javascript
```

i need corresponding code for ios to get values from textfield and convert into date with different time format

Also it is automatically convert into local timezone in javascript, is there any correspondings in ios?

Comment: But in javascript there is some format for inputting date and time and i need the same fromat in ios. eg: date field : May 22, 2000  and May 22 2000 are accepted in javascript without setting dateformat, and in ios is there any such inbuilt method ? or we should define for each format?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the string date format, you can use NSDateFormatter:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Mon, 28 May 2014 1:31:38"; //A date string with a known format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

The `date` variable above will give you the objective-c object that represents the date. You can look at various formats in [Apple's guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) or in [other websites on the internet](http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/nsdateformatter-formatting-strings-reference/)

Comment: So we have to set format for each input? ie for  may 2 2000 and may 2, 2000  i need to set separate format for these? but in javascript no need separate format that is why am confused. Is there any inbuilt method in ios?

Comment: Objective-C is not a high-level language like javascript. It's a thin layer on top of C. As such, objective-C will have fewer features like the ones you're looking for than Java. You may be able to find a open-source library on cocoapods or github that helps transform strings to date in a flexible fashion that you describe. However, I am not aware of any built-in functionality in objective-C that converts strings to dates without specifying a date format.

Answer (score 1):

Generally we'd advise you consider `NSDateFormatter` (see [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) section of the *Data Formatting Guide*). You can then try converting using all of the permutations of the `dateFormat` string until you get a valid date.

Alternatively, you can use [`NSDataDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSError *error;
NSDataDetector *detector = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
NSString *string = @"May 22, 2000";

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [detector firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSLog(@"date = %@", [match date]);

string = @"May 3 2000";

match = [detector firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSLog(@"date = %@", [match date]);
```

The above will find and recognize either of the date formats you suggested. There are limits as to what it can do, but sometimes it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

there is `NSDate` formatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

these links may help you

- http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-2/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: But in javascript there is some format for inputting date and time and i need the same fromat in ios. eg: date field : May 22, 2000  and May 22 2000 are accepted in javascript without setting dateformat, and in ios is there any such inbuilt method ? or we should define for each format?

Comment: yes frnd you just check these links once u will get famlier all thing goes easy as well as iphone is not same as js so accept few changes.